Can you redirect checkout sessions based on customer id?
I am using Stripes "limit to one subscription" feature. It creates and redirects the customer to a portal session, but it uses the email instead of the customer id used to generate the checkout session.
I have a service that provides subscriptions through stripe. When a customer creates account it automatically generates a stripe customer id and stores it for that user. When they go to subscribe a checkout session is generated in by the backend server using their customer id.
I want to use stripe's "limit to one subscription" feature since it's convenient and eliminates some potential headaches. If a user with a subscription clicks on a checkout link, it will redirect them to the billing portal where they can manage their subscriptions. My issue is that it seems to rely on the email associated with the customer id rather than the customer id itself.
This is an issue because the same email can be used for multiple customers and it seems to pick the most recently generated customer id for that email rather than the customer id tied to the checkout session. Is there a way to make sure the portal session generated for the redirect is specific to the customer id for the checkout session. I have no expectation that customers use the same email for stripe as they do for my service and I'd rather not manage all of that internally.
My alternative seems to be to have the backend generate portal session links  based on customer id (if this is even possible) in place of the checkout sessions links if the user is already subscribed. This isn't perfect and doesn't actually handle the case the a user trying to subscribe twice.

Yes it's possible.

Specify a customer when creating a CheckoutSession. If you haven't created a customer yet, create one first.
Append ?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} at the end of the success_url. Stripe will replace the actual Checkout Session ID with {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}
When your customer completes the checkout and gets redirected to the success_url, your server can retrieve the checkout session ID from the URL's query param
Based on the Checkout Session ID, Your server can retrieve the Checkout Session object, get its customer, and return a customized success page.

You can read this doc to learn more about how to customize checkout redirect behaviour.

This seems like it's redirecting on successful checkouts. My question is specific to stripes Limit to 1 subscriber function: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/checkout/limit-subscriptions
It automatically redirects users to their billing portal, but it does so based on the email tied to the customer id not the customer id itself for some reason.
